# What are the main methods to solve an evolution PDE and how are they applied?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

When one sees an evolution PDE, what are the reflexes that he should have in order to tackle it.

What I mean is what are the main methods that have been developed so far and to which kind of PDEs can they be applied to produce what kind of solutions (examples with references of their applications would be appreciated).
For example mollification technique usually can be applied to produce strong solutions but need to be applied to an operator such that its mollication will produce unique approximate solutions that can be shown to converge to a solution in some space.(This is the hard part usually)

I leave the question a little bit open on purpose so that any important suggestion may find its place in here.

Comment: Being more trained in probability than in PDE, my reflex for linear problems $\partial_t u = Lu$ is to try to find a semigroup $P_t$ whose generator is $L$. In view of Ito's formula this can give probabilistic representations of solutions to a variety of problems.

Comment: Also, this question is a bit too open to be productively answered, I think. For instance, hyperbolic and parabolic problems are too different to be addressed with the same techniques.

Comment: There is about a new technique for each new equation, especially for non-linear pde...

Comment: my aim really is just to have an idea of the most important ones that anybody who wants to work in PDE should know and the context in which they can be used.